# Does Jetty 11 have a CORS filter? If not, is there a reason for it?

Tags: java, cors, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have been searching for CORS examples with Jetty 11, and haven't had any success. There is no mention of CORS in the programmer's guide for Jetty 11 either. This makes me wonder if the CORS filter was intentionally omitted from the new version. If the omission is indeed intentional,

- why was that determination made?
- what is the alternative for handling pre-flight CORS requests?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Jetty 11 has a `CrossOriginFilter`.

Evidence:

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-11.0.7/jetty-servlets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/CrossOriginFilter.java

Comment: Thank you. I feel silly for not having the right dependencies when I was searching